# How to access one ViewModel propery/ Data in another ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container

Ya I googled it many times, and searched in many forums, but I did not got what exactly what i want.

In simple terms, I have Main window, in that first I should display `LoginUserControl`, when user click on button present in `LoginUserControl`, it should move to `GameUserControl`, again when he clicks on button in `GameUserControl`, it should move to `LoginUserControl`.

I'm using MVVM pattern and Unity for `DependencyInjection` (when i searched, I heard its easy to maintain the instances through it).

Here is what I tried till now :

MainView:

```
 <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ShowControl}" />
    </Grid>
```

MainViewModel :

```
 class MainWindowViewModel : Bindable, IMainViewModel 
{
    private UserControl showControl;
    public UserControl ShowControl
    {
        get
        {
            if (showControl == null)
                showControl = App.Container.Resolve<LoginView>();
            return showControl;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref showControl, value);
        }
    }
}
```

LoginView :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Display}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Navigate to Game View" Command="{Binding Navigae}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyData, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="2" Margin="52,24,76,31" />
</Grid>
```

LoginView.cs :

```
public LoginView(IMainViewModel mainViewModel)
    {
        this.DataContext = new LoginViewModel(mainViewModel);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

LoginViewModel :

```
public class LoginViewModel : Bindable
{
    // Bindable which implements INotifyPropertyChanged Event

    IMainViewModel mainViewModel;
    public LoginViewModel(IMainViewModel mainViewModel)
    {
        this.mainViewModel = mainViewModel;
        this.Navigae = new RelayCommand(execute, canExecute);
        display = "login view";
        myData = "Gopi ";
    }

    private bool canExecute(object arg)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void execute(object obj)
    {
       // mainViewModel.ShowControl = App.Container.Resolve<GameView>();
       // here I want to access the ShowControl property from MainViewModel and update it
    }

    public ICommand Navigae
    {
        get; set;
    }

    private string display;

    public string Display
    {
        get
        {
            return display;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref display, value);
        }
    }

    private string myData;

    public string MyData
    {
        get
        {
            return myData;
        }
        set
        {
            myData = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In the same way I have GameView, GameView.cs and GameViewModel (only the name changes w.r.t. LoginView)

IMainViewModel : (It is used as Repository which I seen in some examples)

```
public interface IMainViewModel
{

}
```

I'm using unity because I dont want to create new Instances every time when I clicked the button. when we are using unity it will create instance for first time and use the same for later.

Here is the code of App.cs :

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static IUnityContainer _container;
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        ConfigureContainer();
        Application.Current.MainWindow = _container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    private void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        _container = new UnityContainer();
        _container.RegisterType<IMainViewModel, MainWindowViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }

    public static IUnityContainer Container
    {
        get
        {
            return _container;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone guide me from this point.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you consider viewmodel first navigation.

As an aside / observation:

Resolving MainWindowViewModel out of unity seems to be because you want to pass it into the other viewmodels.  And that's all you're passing into the child viewmodels.  Even if you intend mocking mainwindowviewmodel then you could just do so by instantiating your mock in your test code.

Your dependency injection just seems to be complicating things at this stage.

/ Aside.

Consider the approach in this:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-do-not-use-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

MainWindowViewmodel controls navigation.
You want to do that from buttons in child controls in code like the sample? No problem. You can use relativesource binding on your command and bind a button in the child control to a command in mainwindowviewmodel.  You could Bind the commandparameter from the child viewmodel if you need some data from that.

That mainwindowviewmodel then instantiates any child viewmodels rather than their usercontrol doing so.  Mainwindowviewmodel could pass a reference to itself in if that was still necessary.

Comment: hi, in the link you provided, they are taking every viewmodel into collection. But it should not be the ideal case, if we have n number of VM then we can't do like that. If possible can you explain it in some code format navigation part. Anyway I'll be looking into it. Thanks for your time

Comment: Bear in mind that's a simple introductory kind of an example.  If you wanted to retain state then you need to keep a reference to them somewhere. If you don't then you can just pass a Type and activator createinstance(ThatType) every time.  Or you could resolve them each time and use configuration to define the lifetime of each type. There are many options. It's a mainstream pattern - you will find a bunch of samples if you google.

Comment: OK, will look into that. Thanks :)